# How do I reverse the scroll direction in Animonscroll.js?

Tags: jquery, django-templates, jquery-masonry

After weeks of troubleshooting why Animonscroll is not working, I discovered that it actually is working, but for some reason it's reversed.  In other words, if I load my page and scroll down, the images are there, but the loading animation is not in effect.  However, if I scroll down to the bottom of the page, THEN refresh that page, I am able to scroll up and the images animate as they come into view from the top of the screen.  Why this is happening, I have no idea, I have taken the stock code from the Masonry Tympanus demo.  The only difference is my html looks more something like this because I'm using Django.

```
<ul class="grid effect-8" id="grid">
    {% for i in latest_entries %}
    <li>
      <div class="grid_4">
       <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img src="{{ i.item_picture.url }}" alt="" />
        <div class="overlayname">{{ i.headline }}</div>
        <div class="overlayprice">{{ i.price1 }}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I don't know if this issue is related to the way Django handles things?  I have no idea.  The only solution I can think of is to go into the AnimOnScroll and somehow reverse which way the animation occurs?  I am open to any other suggestions.  Here is the AnimonScroll.js code below.

```
if ( !window.requestAnimationFrame ) {

    window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
              function( callback, element) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };
    })();
}

;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var pluginName = "animOnScroll",
        defaults = {
            'smoothing': true,
            'from': {},
            'to': {},
            'scrollbarPosition': 0,
            'smoothScrollbarPosition': 0,
            'realScrollbarPosition': 0,
            'scrolling': true,
            'scrollerTimeout': 0,
            'supportsTransform': false,
            'vendorPrefix': {},
            'useTransforms': true,
            'speed': .6,
            'animations': [],
            'alwaysShow': false
        };

        function animOnScroll(element, options){
            this.element = $(element);
            this.parent = $(element).parent();
            this._config = ( typeof options !== 'undefined' ) ? $.extend({},defaults,options) : defaults;

            var vendors = ['webkit','Moz','o','ms',''],
                d = document.createElement("div");

            for ( var i = 0; i < vendors.length; i++ ) {
                if ( typeof d.style[ vendors[i] + 'Transform'] !== 'undefined' ) {
                    this._config.vendorPrefix = { 'css': '-' + vendors[i] + '-', 'event': vendors[i] };
                    this._config.supportsTransform = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }

            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/gi)){ //ie9 transforms are unreliable
                this._config.supportsTransform = false;
                this._config.useTransforms = false;
            }

            this.init();
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.init = function(){
            for ( var i = 0; i < this._config.animations.length; i++ ) {
                this._config.animations[ i ] = this.prepareAnimation( this._config.animations[ i ] );
            }
            this.self = this.element,
            this._globals = {
                'currentState': {},
                'targetState': {},
                'css': {},
                'transitionComplete': false,
                'supports3D': ('WebKitCSSMatrix' in window && 'm11' in new WebKitCSSMatrix()),
                'currentAnimation': {},
                'animationIndex': -1,
                'isAnimating': true
            };

            if ( !window.animOnScroll_broadcaster ) {
                window.animOnScroll_broadcaster = new animOnScroll_broadcaster().init();
            }

            //if transforms are supported offload easing to CSS transition
            this.initTransition();
            if ( this._config.animations.length > 0 ) { this._globals.currentAnimation = this._config.animations[0]; }
            $(window).bind('scroll', bindHandler(this, function( e ) { this._config.scrolling = true; }));
            this.anim();
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.initTransition = function(){
            if ( this._config.supportsTransform && this._config.useTransforms ) {
                this._config.smoothing = false;
                this.element.css( this.applyVendorPrefixes({
                    'transition': 'all ' + this._config.speed + 's cubic-bezier(0,0,.2,1)',
                    'transform-style': 'preserve-3d',
                    'backface-visibility': 'hidden'
                }));
            }
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.applyVendorPrefixes = function( css ) {
            var prefixed = {};
            for ( var p in css ) {
                if ( p.match(/(transform|transition|animation|backface\-visibility)/gi)) {
                    prefixed[ this._config.vendorPrefix.css + p] = css[p];
                } else {
                    prefixed[p] = css[p];
                }
            }
            return prefixed;
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.prepareAnimation = function(animation){
            if ( typeof animation !== 'undefined' ) {

                if ( typeof animation.from === 'undefined' ) { animation['from'] = {}; }

                if ( emptyObject( animation.from ) ) {

                    if ( !emptyObject( animation.to ) ) {

                        for ( var p in animation.to ) {
                            if ( animation.to.hasOwnProperty(p) ) {
                                if ( p == 'rotate' ) { 
                                    if ( this._config.supportsTransform && this._config.useTransforms ) { animation.from[ p ] = 0; }    
                                } else if ( p == 'scale' ) { 
                                    if ( this._config.supportsTransform && this._config.useTransforms ) { animation.from[ p ] = 1; }
                                } else if ( p == 'left' ) {
                                    if ( this._config.supportsTransform && this._config.useTransforms ) {
                                        animation['from'][ p ] = 0;
                                    } else {
                                        animation['from'][ p ] = this.getStyle(this.element[0], p);
                                        animation['to'][p] += animation['from'][ p ];
                                    }
                                } else if ( p == 'top' ) { 
                                    if ( this._config.supportsTransform && this._config.useTransforms ) {
                                        animation['from'][ p ] = 0; 
                                    } else {
                                        animation['from'][ p ] = this.getStyle(this.element[0], p);
                                        animation['to'][p] += animation['from'][ p ];
                                    }
                                } else if ( p == 'bottom' ) { 
                                    if ( this._config.supportsTransform && this._config.useTransforms ) {
                                        animation['from'][ p ] = 0; 
                                    } else {
                                        animation['from'][ p ] = this.getStyle(this.element[0], p);
                                        animation['to'][p] -= animation['from'][ p ];
                                    }
                                }
                                else { animation.from[ p ] = this.getStyle(this.element[0], p); }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            return animation;
        }


        animOnScroll.prototype.getStyle = function(el, cssprop){
            if (el.currentStyle) //IE
                return parseInt( el.currentStyle[cssprop] );
            else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) //Firefox
                return parseInt( document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop] );
            else //try and get inline style
                return parseInt( el.style[cssprop] );
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.selectAnimation = function() {
            var a = this._config.animations,
                len = a.length;
            while ( len-- ) {
                if ( this.inAnimateZone( a[ len ] ) && this._globals.animationIndex != len ) {
                    this._globals.animationIndex = len;
                    this._globals.currentAnimation = a[ len ];
                } else if ( this.inBeforeAnimateZone( a[ len ] ) && this._globals.animationIndex != len ) {
                    this._globals.animationIndex = len;
                    this._globals.currentAnimation = a[ len ];
                }
            }
            if ( a.length == 0 ) { this._globals.currentAnimation = { startOn: _config.startOn, endOn: _config.endOn, to: _config.to, from: _config.from }; }
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.notAnimating = function(){
            var a = this._config.animations;
            if ( a[ a.length -1 ].endOn - this._config.scrollbarPosition <= -(window.innerHeight*5) || a[0].startOn - this._config.scrollbarPosition >= (window.innerHeight*3) ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.anim = function() {

            if ( this._config.scrolling ) {

                if ( this._config.smoothing ) {
                    this._config.scrollbarPosition += (window.animOnScroll_realScrollbarPosition - this._config.scrollbarPosition) * .08;
                    if ( Math.abs(this._config.scrollbarPosition - window.animOnScroll_realScrollbarPosition ) < .1) {
                        this._config.scrollbarPosition = window.animOnScroll_realScrollbarPosition;
                    }
                } else {
                    this._config.scrollbarPosition = window.animOnScroll_realScrollbarPosition;
                }

                if ( !this._config.alwaysShow ){
                    if ( this.notAnimating() ) {
                        this.element.css('display','none');
                        this._globals.isAnimating = false;
                    } else {
                        this.element.css('display','block');
                        this._globals.isAnimating = true;
                    }
                }

                if ( this._globals.isAnimating ) {

                    this.selectAnimation();

                    if ( this.inBeforeAnimateZone(this._globals.currentAnimation) ) {

                        for ( var p in this._globals.currentAnimation.from ) { this._globals.currentState[ p ] = this._globals.currentAnimation.from[ p ]; }

                    } else if ( this.inAnimateZone(this._globals.currentAnimation) ) {

                        var d = this._config.scrollbarPosition - this._globals.currentAnimation.startOn,
                            percent = (d / ( this._globals.currentAnimation.endOn -  this._globals.currentAnimation.startOn )).toFixed(4);

                        for ( var p in this._globals.currentAnimation.to ) {

                            var originalDelta = parseInt(this._globals.currentAnimation.to[ p ]) - parseInt( this._globals.currentAnimation.from[ p ]),
                                val = ( (p == 'top' || p == 'left' || p == 'bottom') && this._config.supportsTransform ) ? this._globals.currentAnimation.from[ p ] + originalDelta * percent : parseInt( this._globals.currentAnimation.from[ p ]) + originalDelta * percent;
                            this._globals.currentState[ p ] = val;
                        }

                    } else {

                        for ( var p in this._globals.currentAnimation.to ) { this._globals.currentState[ p ] = this._globals.currentAnimation.to[ p ]; }
                    }

                    this.element.css( this.getCSS() );
                }
                this._config.scrolling = window.animOnScroll_realScrollbarPosition != this._config.scrollbarPosition;
            }

            requestAnimationFrame( bindHandler(this, this.anim), 1000/60);

        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.getCSS = function() {
            var transform = '',
                translate = '';

            for ( var p in this._globals.currentState ) {
                switch ( p ) {
                    case 'rotate':
                        transform += ' rotate(' + this._globals.currentState[ p ].toFixed(4) + 'deg)';
                        break;
                    case 'scale':
                        transform += ' scale(' + this._globals.currentState[ p ] + ')';
                        break;
                    case 'opacity':
                        this._globals.css[ p ] = this._globals.currentState[ p ];
                        break;
                    case 'top':
                        if ( this._config.supportsTransform ) {
                            translate += ' translateY(' + this._globals.currentState[ p ].toFixed(2) + 'px)';
                        } else {
                            this._globals.css[ p ] = this._globals.currentState[ p ] + 'px';
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'bottom':
                        if ( this._config.supportsTransform ) {
                            translate += ' translateY(' + this._globals.currentState[ p ].toFixed(2) + 'px)';
                        } else {
                            this._globals.css[ p ] = this._globals.currentState[ p ] + 'px';
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'left':
                        if ( this._config.supportsTransform ) {
                            translate += ' translateX(' + this._globals.currentState[ p ].toFixed(2) + 'px)';
                        } else {
                            this._globals.css[ p ] = this._globals.currentState[ p ] + 'px';
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        this._globals.css[ p ] = this._globals.currentState[ p ] + 'px';
                }
            }

            if ( transform != '' || translate != '' ) {
                if ( this._globals.supports3D ) { translate += ' translateZ(0px)'; }
                transform = translate + transform;
                this._globals.css[ this._config.vendorPrefix.css + 'transform'] = transform;
            }

            return this._globals.css;
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.inAnimateZone = function( animation ) {
            if ( typeof animation !== 'undefined' ) {
                return this._config.scrollbarPosition > animation.startOn && this._config.scrollbarPosition < animation.endOn;
            }
            return this._config.scrollbarPosition > this._config.startOn && this._config.scrollbarPosition < this._config.endOn;
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.inBeforeAnimateZone = function( animation ) {
            if ( typeof animation !== 'undefined' ) {
                return this._config.scrollbarPosition <= animation.startOn;
            }
            return this._config.scrollbarPosition <= this._config.startOn;
        }

        animOnScroll.prototype.inAfterAnimateZone = function( animation) {
            if ( typeof animation !== 'undefined' ) {
                return this._config.scrollbarPosition > animation.endOn;
            }
            return this._config.scrollbarPosition > this._config.endOn;
        }


        //utility functions
        function emptyObject( o ) {
            for ( var p in o ) { return false; }
            return true;
        }

        function normalizeCSS( css ) {
            var newCSS = {};
            for ( var p in css ) {
                newCSS[ p ] = parseInt(css[ p ]);
            }
            return newCSS;
        }

        function bindHandler( scope, func ) {
            return function() { func.apply(scope, arguments); }
        }

        function animOnScroll_broadcaster(){
            this.init = function(){
                if (!window.animOnScroll_realScrollbarPosition && !window.animOnScroll_isScrolling) {
                    window.animOnScroll_realScrollbarPosition = 0;
                    window.animOnScroll_isScrolling = false;
                }
                $(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
                    window.animOnScroll_realScrollbarPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
                    window.animOnScroll_isScrolling = true;
                });
                return this;
            }
        }

        $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
            return this.each(function () {
                if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                    $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                    new animOnScroll( this, options ));
                }
            });
        }

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: animOnScroll looks like an abandoned project. Documentation is insubstantial and the last update was 2 years ago.

Comment: Yea I noticed that :/  I hoped that by posting this, someone who is jquery savvy could identify how to reverse this so that the animation triggers when scrolling down instead of up.